# How to set multiple MX records in AWS Route 53 using Java SDK 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, mx-record

I'm using the AWS Route 53 Java SDK 2 `software.amazon.awssdk:software.amazon.awssdk:route53:2.8.3` with OpenJDK 11 on Windows 10. I want to set two separate `MX` records with different priorities, e.g.

- `10 smpt1.example.com.`
- `20 smpt2.example.com.`

If I set those as separate resource records, the last one overrides the first one, so that I only wind up with `20 smpt2.example.com`. I read on an [AWS forum thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=88634) that I need to combine the values into one resource record, with each MX record on a separate line, so I tried setting combining the values using `"\n"` (e.g. joining them with a newline character):

```
10 smpt1.example.com.
20 smpt2.example.com.
```

However that produces an error:

> … software.amazon.awssdk.services.route53.model.InvalidChangeBatchException: [Invalid Resource Record: FATAL problem: MXRRDATANotTwoFields (MX record doesn't have 2 fields) encountered with '10 smtp1.example.com.
>
> 20 smtp2.example.com.'] (Service: Route53, Status Code: 400, Request ID: …

(Note that the error output starts `20.smtp2.example.com` on a new line, indicating that there is a newline character. The Stack Overflow formatter above was removing the newline, so I added an extra blank line to illustrate. The blank line does not occur in the actual error message.)

So I'm stuck. How do I set two MX domains with different priorities in Route 53 using the Java SDK 2?

*Update:* This seems to be a pretty big blocker issue. Surely it can't be that Route 53 doesn't handle multiple `MX` records using the Java SDK 2. Is it completely broken? I've opened [Issue #1484](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1484) with no responses so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had made a mistake in using the Route 53 API model, forgetting that Route 53 groups multiple values for a single name and type into a *resource record set*. The `ResourceRecordSet` class has multiple `ResourceRecord`s, each of which contains only a single *value*. The "resource record set" has a name+type that functions as a key for the set. In other words, I have to group all my values for the same name and type into this `ResourceRecordSet`, and set them together in a single API call.

My mistake earlier is that I wrote code to set a single value in a `ResourceRecordSet`, and then I was trying to call that code multiple times, which results in multiple "sets" for the same name+value key, each of which subsequently would replace the previous ones. Once I realized this, I had to refactor the code to group the resource records by name+value and put all the values into a `ResourceRecordSet` and use `UPSERT` to set them all at the same time.